# What's the better practice for testing code which relies on a DB? Mocks and stubs? Or seeded data?

Tags: database, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

Seems like forever I've read that, when testing, use a mock database object or repository.  No reason to test someone else's DB code, right?  No need to have your code actually mess with data in a database, right?

Now lately I see tests which set up a database (possibly in-memory) and seed it with test data, just for running tests against.

Is one approach better than the other?  If tests with seeded data are worth running, should one even bother with mock databases connections?  If so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to test code that interacts with a database.

The repository pattern is one method of creating a facade over the data access code. It makes it easy to stub/mock out the repository during test. This is useful when a piece of business logic needs tested in isolation and dummy values can help test different branches of the code.

Fake databases (in-memory or local files) are less common because there needs to be some "middle-ware" that knows how to read data from a real database and a fake database. It usually just makes sense to have a repository over the whole thing and mock out the repository. This approach is more feasible in some older systems where there is an existing infrastructure. For instance, you use a real database and then switch over to a fake database for test performance reasons.

Another option is using an actual database, populating it with bogus data. This approach is slower and requires writing a lot of scripts. However, this approach is fairly common as part of integration testing. I used to write a lot of "transactional" tests where I used a database transaction to rollback changes after running my tests. I'd write one large test that collectively performed all of my CRUD operations on a particular table.

The last approach makes sense when you are testing the code that converts SQL results into your objects. Your SQL could be invalid (or you use the wrong stored procedure name). It is also easy to forget to check for nulls, perform an invalid cast, etc. when mapping to objects. This code should be tested at some point. An ORM can help alleviate a lot of this testing.

I am typically pretty lazy these days. I use repositories. Most of my data layer code is touched when performing actual integration tests (hitting a real database with dummy data), so I don't bother testing individual database calls (no more transactional tests). I also use ORMs for doing most of my SELECT statements. I think a lot of the industry is moving towards this more lazy approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should use both.

The business services should rely on DAOs, and be tested by mocking the DAOs. This allows for fast, easy to implement, easy to maintain tests.

The DAOs unique responsibility is to contain database access code (queries, etc.), and should also be tested. So you should use a test database, with test data, and check that their queries return/save what they're support to return/save.

I'm not a big fan of using an in-memory database, different from the one used in production. The behavior of some queries, constraints, etc. will be different from database to database, and you'd better be sure that the code will work on the production database, and not in an in-memory database used only by tests.